# How do I call the phone's default add to contact menu?

Tags: android, contacts

Okay, I am building a small directory app. I am wondering: given a particular number on some activity view, what method handles calling the phone's default "add to contacts / send sms" menu?

What I want is that when the user clicks a particular number, then pops up the phone's default menu for adding the number to contacts, making a call or sending an sms to that number. (I've noticed on Samsung phones, all three options (adding to contacts, calling the number, sms-ing the number) are available on the phone's default menu.) It doesn't have to be all the options though, just want to access this menu of the system.

Similarly, I am wondering: given a particular email address that a user clicks on, how can we then have the menu that allows the user to choose to send an email via the phone's default mailing software?

Can anyone also point me to the correct naming for these methods in the Android APIs? I can do more searching having known what these things are called.

Thanks. Sorry about all the 3 questions in one, but they are so related, don't think we need separate threads for the 3, do we?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am looking for (Android Intents) is actually here for anyone who may stumble upon this question.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html#intents_overview